# Verify date format in Marklogic

Tags: marklogic

I want to identify the documents which have incorrect(as per our project standard) date format in one of it's element eg: . Our application standard date format is '[MNn,*-3] [D01], [Y]'. So I am traversing through all the `<document-create-date>` and want to identify documents whose date field value do not match '[MNn,*-3] [D01], [Y]' format. Please let me know how to match date formats in marklogic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the String [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to evaluate whether the date value matches a regex pattern for your custom date format.

```
if (documentCreateDate.match(/[A-Z][a-z]{2} \d{2}, \d{4})) {
  "date is valid"
} else {
  "date is invalid"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the least processor/memory intensive may be to use a lexicon (overriding the default tokenizing) and use some combination of a [`cts:not-query()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:not-query) and do the term expansion using [`cts:element-value-match`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-value-match) the logic here being that documents with invalid patterns would not make it into the result set (because they would be excluded in the rem expansion on the lexicon match). Therefore, constructing something around this and a `cts:not-query()` should work.

Then it comes down to if this is more proficient than some more complex index, since this approach would feed a large term list to the query.

Comment: This is not related to search api. I need javascript code for date format compare with '[MNn,-3] [D01], [Y]' format

Comment: Absolutely *nothing* about your inquiry states anything about javascript. It is only tagged as MarkLogic. I suggest that you be clear in your request..